# fstrim not supported on USB flashdrive?

Tags: 14.04, server, usb, trim

Not sure this has already been properly sorted (but I am a noob)

New install of 14.04 server installed on a brand new SanDisk 16Gb USB stick mounted on the internal USB connector of a HP Proliant Microserver. Stick contains boot, root, minimal user files and swap as per default installation, LVM *not* installed. System basically runs fine as a headless file/media server.

Weekly CRON job fails

```
fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
```

hdparm and smartctl both show

```
Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
```

but the command `fstrim -v /` produces the same failure message

```
fstrim: /: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
```

Although there isn't much writing to the USB stick (apart from system log files, I guess) it would be good to know just what's going on here.

Comment: What filesystem do you have on USB-stick?

Comment: whatever the guided installation default is, (ext4 and a small swap partition?). Looking at WebMin it would seem that 13.05Gb is the main filestore, and 1.92Gb is the swap partition.

Comment: The server probably detects your Sandisk as an SSD and tries to do a `trim` on it (which it apparently doesn't support). Can you provide the output of `cat /etc/crontab` ?

Comment: There is a cron job to run a trim once a week, it would appear.

Answer (score 4):

[Bug 1336541](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1336541) is "No TRIM via USB".  I guess the problems are present with internal USB ports also.  Additionally in your case, it sounds like you are using a USB flash stick, not a SSD device -- TRIM would not apply to flash.  If you device is really an SSD, do add yourself to the bug.

Comment: I am using a USB stick, not an SSD connected some other way. But what puzzles me is that the device itself says it supports trim operations. Yet the OS clearly doesn't like it.

Comment: @BobWalton where does it say it supports TRIM functions?

Comment: As per original post,
`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sde | grep "TRIM supported"`
produces
`Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)`

Answer (score 0):

Certain USB enclosures will pass the `trim ioctl` which is different than the `info` command ioctl. Just because the drive reports it supports trim, does not mean `fstrim` will be correctly translated, i.e. pass through the bridge in the USB enclosure to the drive itself.

If you have a USB enclosure with a bridge `chip` that passes the trim command, you're part way there. Next, you need a `udev` rule. Try `linux # nano 50-usb-trim.rules` Copy and paste this into the file `ACTION=="add|change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="152d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0562", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", ATTR{provisioning_mode}="unmap"` but for the `152d` and `0562` run `lsusb` and locate your usb enclosure, which will usually contain the word `bridge`

There are 2 4-digit hex numbers separated by a colon, in my case `152d:0562`, but use the numbers from your USB enclosure, and put them in the proper places, like I did in mine.

Save the udev rule file above, and put it in `/etc/udev/rules.d` After you connect the USB drive, Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` Locate the drive in /dev `linux # ls /dev/sd*`. If you still can't figure out which one it is, use `linux # sudo fdisk -l` and look at the sizes. You can probably tell from that which drive you want to trim.

`linux # sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt` but substitute tyh